# xaxt = n not working when ploting a list in r

Tags: r, plot, axis

I'm trying to make a plot of some results which are in the form of a list and I want to make an r plot with a custom x-axis, the problem is that `xaxt = 'n'` is not working for some reason. Maybe someone has an idea or a workaround for this issue. This is how my graph looks, the axis are one on top of the other

[image: the plot]

Here is the code I am using:

```
plot(spi_1_gamma, xlim = c(1989,2019), ylim = c(-3,4),
     main ='Terlinga, Brewster,Tx, SPI_Gamma-1', xaxt = "n")
axis(side = 1, at = 1989:2019, tick = 1,las = 2)
```

For the data that I am using, I  am not sure how to share it because it is a spei object from the spei package so I will tr this

```
data <- head(spi_1_gamma)
dput(data)
```

Comment: Hi, we can't run your code without data, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038 As you see, it's not neded to share the entire original data, just a minimal example that resembles it.

Comment: [`spei::plot.spei`](https://github.com/cran/SPEI/blob/ed81002b9fd25e1b9142325c8998c822ead447eb/R/spei.R) *accepts* arbitrary arguments (via `...`), but does not reference `xaxt` [anywhere in the package](https://github.com/cran/SPEI/search?q=xaxt). I think you need to reach out to the authors and put in a feature request.